# Object Stored State is Changing

Tags: java

I have a game that keeps track of board configurations and each "Player" is an object with different properties. I'm creating an "undo" function that stores the different configurations each turn.  The problem is the Player object is stored at say State 1, then State 2, then State 3. But the properties of the Player object change in state 1 every time the configuration changes.  So the Player object is essentially the same for all states. It is the current state.

I'm guessing it's an issue with variable binding, but can't make sense of how it applies to this situation.

Comment: Without code, one can only infer, but I wonder if `static` appears in any variables you're not expecting to change...

Comment: I also have a couple of singleton classes.  I'm not sure if that would affect it.

Comment: I can't say for sure.  I'd need to see code to actually validate what's going on.  As it is, there's just not enough info to answer your question.

Comment: If it's changing,  that's because you're changing it. Either the information is being shared between players when you didn't intend it to be, or something is calling a method on this Player which is changing it. Look at all the places you're altering it. If you've got a debugger, breakpoint those and/or set up a watchpoint on the variable (a breakpoint which fires whenever the variable changes) and make sure this is happening only when you intended it to happen. And yeah, watch out for statics or other state which is shared between players, intended or not.

Comment: yes I'm changing it.  I guess if I change the actual object, it will always change. I guess I have to break down the object, store it, and then create new objects.